# Get a list of Product Categories inside a loop

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to list out product categories as a list

Farm Cycle: 6 Months

KADUNA

The code below output as 
Farm Cycle: 6 Months, KADUNA

```
add_action( 'wpo_wcpdf_after_item_meta', 'wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories', 10, 3 );
function wpo_wcpdf_show_product_categories ( $template_type, $item, $order ) {
    // get a comma separated list of categories (category links stripped)
    if (isset($item['product'])) {

        echo '<div class="product-categories">DETAILS:<br/> '.strip_tags( wc_get_product_category_list( $item['product']->get_id() ) ).'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code this will give you categories in list format:
     `echo '<ul>' . wc_get_product_category_list( $item['product']->get_id(), '</li><li>', '<li>',  '</li>' ) . '</ul>';`

Comment: It works fine but how can I strip the tags, I tried

<code>
echo '<ul>'  .strip_tags(wc_get_product_category_list( $item['product']->get_id(), '</li><li>', '<li>',  '</li>' )) . '</ul>';
</code>

Comment: If you will strip the tags then it will not display as a list.

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate your help, how can I exclude a particular category

Comment: I was able to replace the URL using 
preg_replace('/\b((https?|ftp|file):\/\/|www\.)[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i'